# How can I export a solution's History from Visual Studio 2012 to a spreadsheet?

Tags: tfs

Probably a dumb question, apologies and red-face in advance.

I want be able to export the commit history of a project from Visual Studio 2012 to a spreadsheet. I can do it manually with copy-and-paste but that's stupid. We use Team Foundation Service (not 'Server'), which doesn't appear to have this kind of reporting.

I could use a git client - but before I do that, does anyone know a less roundabout way? Is there a 'Export History to csv' menu item somewhere?

Cheers,
Andy

Comment: You can use the TF command line utility to dump this info to a file.